# Use Vuex 4 with Vue 2.7

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex4

Is there an easy way to use Vuex 4 with Vue 2.7?
In the docs for Vuex 4 it says you have to `use(store)` on an app instance created through `createApp`, but this function is not backported from Vue 3 to Vue 2.7.
I am fine with hacky solutions, since I will be using this only temporarily while I "upgrade" to Pinia

Comment: There's no way at all. It's for Vue 3. It's unclear what's the point of using use(store) in your case.

Comment: Also, why do you want to use Vuex4? Maybe Pinia could be a nice fit too?

Comment: I WANT to use Pinia, the problem is the Vuex store in my app is really big and I need a transition phase to migrate from Vuex to Pinia. For that I would like to have both in that phase. Needless to say that I would switch instantly if I could ;-)

Comment: Is the transition easier from Vuex4? If not, try to make it right now IMO. You can maybe do it incrementally too.

Comment: I don't think the transition will be easier, the time management would be better, though. My ideal plan would be to first do all the ugly migration stuff ... mixins, extends, event bus etc. to get to Vue 3 fast and then take my time for Pinia. For that it would be cool if not only Pinia but also Vuex 4 hat vue-demi or another compat layer built-in to work with both Vue 2 and Vue 3